# Angular UI modal directive, backdrop missing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have no backdrop when using the modal directive from UI Bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. The modal itself is working.

I have tried with both the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js (template included) and without templates (downloading them manually). I compared the the markup and the css with the one from the example and I can't find any difference. Everything is there. I've used it several times before  and this is the first time I encounter this issue. The difference this time is that I'm using the sass version of bootstrap. Maybe has something to do with it? I'm out of ideas where to look.

My versions:

```
"angular": "1.2.24",
"angular-animate": "~1.2.24"
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
"bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.1",
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Hmm, I've encountered also many issues with angular-ui modal, therefore I just started using AngularStrap (introduced in ng-europe), should check it out: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/ , it worked much better for me

Comment: What version of twitter bootstrap are you on, also what version of UI directives?

Comment: @JMK updated question with versions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from Maxisam's link to the pull request: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/3117

the easiest fix is simply to add the following CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Hopefully it won't break your code :-)

Comment: I downgraded from Bootstrap 3.2.0 to 3.1.1, as suggested by @per-ström, prior to applying this CSS. I'm not sure if the downgrade was necessary, but the combined effect has resolved the issue.

Comment: This fix worked for me on ui-bootstrap 0.12.1 and Bootstrap 3.2.2, so downgrading probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, downgrading is less than ideal and I'd rather not inject $document whenever possible. This did the trick and the behaviour worked as expected.

Answer (score 10):

There is a workaround you can do

1- add this css class:

```
.modal-backdrop{
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
}
```

2- make sure the "window.html" template file included "ng-click" event

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)">
    <div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: position fixed help me! was added to bottom:0; Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As the docs on angular-ui points out. It supports Bootstrap 3.1.1. So the solution was to downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the answer, where `bottom:0;` is specified is not entirely correct - in some cases it happens (and that's especially true for ui-view router), that there is some empty space left below the backdrop. So, I would suggest just adding the following code:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    bottom: -100%;
}
```

As the backdrop is added to the body level, it should not break anything and is absolutely guaranteed not to leave any uncovered space below the backdrop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [PR](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/3117)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vlGufEpKnXp7B4CrK64Z?p=preview)

Basically you just need to add one line in directive 'modalWindow'

```
angular.element($document[0].querySelectorAll('div.modal-backdrop')).css('height',element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
```

and inject **$document**