# AngularStrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am trying to do the modal using AngularStrap. Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular-Strap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angular-motion/dist/angular-motion.min.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" bs-modal="modal">Toggle Modal</button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.modal = {
        "title": "Title",
        "content": "Hello Modal<br />This is a multiline message!"
    };
});
```

When I test on browser, the modal does appear. But the content `<br />` is being displayed on the modal. It does not turn into new line. Also, the modal background does not turn into grey color.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you bind content? do you bind it using "ng-bind-html" please look at this url https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should include [angular sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) to let angular to deal with html:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Then, according to [AngularStrap Modal docs](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals#modals-usage) you should add `html="true"` attribute to your modal directive attributes:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" bs-modal="modal" html="true">Toggle Modal</button>
```

That's it.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/j4xL7hmq/1/) with dirty CSS fix for a modal backdrop.

The dirty (IMHO) CSS fix for backdrop having height 0 (you probably won't need it on a site with relatively positioned content in it, however i stretch the height of backdrop to the whole height):

```
.modal-backdrop {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

P.S. Always be careful if you include user inputted text in your HTML. Read about [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Read [angular $sanitize docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now the content is display in 2 lines. But the modal background is still not in grey color. How can I make it grey?

Comment: When I used Firefox's Inspect element I saw 0 for model backdrop computed height.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926798/angular-ui-modal-directive-backdrop-missing here you can see same problem (it seems to be same). I've updated the fiddle with dirty CSS fix for this: http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/j4xL7hmq/1/.

Comment: it should be noted also in their documentation!